# "Accept for more help" extortion - is this common?

Tags: discussion, comments, abuse

I was answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924812/android-number-formating-exception/) and noticed that there was an element of extortion involved which put an extra burden on the OP's question.

Is this allowed?

The deleted comment was in the context of "If you mark this solution as accepted then I will help you", which resulted in the OP having to deal with extra issues as a result - such as changing the database columns and getting null pointer exceptions.

I know it sounds trivial but was dismayed to see that being played out.

I did comment the person who answered, in their retaliation, the downvote of my answer ensued. The person's answer was subsequently marked as accepted (but: meanwhile deleted), and despite that, the OP was new to the arena of Android/Java programming.

What can be done about this?

Comment: I downvoted his answer and upvoted yours to balance the universe.

Comment: As an aside, as for *"extra issues as a result - such as changing the database columns"* — as far as I can tell, the OP already had Double columns in the database? (Not sure why the accepted answer claims that need changing. Also wondering why one would want to store longitude and latitude as integer values.)

Comment: But, wait... With 16k on Stack Overflow, you're asking *us* if this is common...?

Comment: It was the first time I ever saw that being played out in all my time with SO and did raise the mod's attention on that and wanted to be certain for myself if this was an appropriate thing to do in terms of meta :)

Comment: Definitely flag this.  This will not be tolerated on SO and we'll [give warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924812/android-number-formating-exception/11924973#comment15902875_11924968) to people that engage in that kind of behavior, at the least.

Comment: I saw this recently too... a different user, on multiple occasions, had replied to questions on his answers as "up-vote/accept and I will help you." I absolutely agree these should be flagged. If the OP has additional questions or is trying to get clarification, the answerer shouldn't require a ransom before the answer is necessarily useful to the OP.

Comment: @casperOne, just in case things were different than they might seem: *maybe* the OP first unaccepted and asked for further detail—the blackmail kind of going the other way. I obviously cannot tell, but the OP [has been accepting, unaccepting, accepting, unaccepting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11924812/timeline). (Not expecting you to provide details; just to let you know in case you annotated/registered something with the account of the answerer.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Flag the post for moderator attention (use the `other` option) and explain your suspicions.

Blackmail such as that is *not* tolerated on the SE family of sites, but it's up to the moderators to investigate and take action. They can also see deleted comments to gather evidence.

Comment: Thanks - I did that alright but just have to see what happens :)