# Is voting on posts linked to from Meta discouraged?

Tags: discussion, voting, hyperlinks

I'm wondering if voting on posts linked to from Meta discouraged. For example, if a user posts something like this:

> **Why Was My Post Closed?**
>
> I have a post, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/randomquestion.
> Why was this question closed?

Would voting on the linked question be discouraged because doing so would make it generate additional votes from the Meta question, or would it be fine to vote as I normally would?

Comment: I don't see how it would make a difference. There's nobody here anyway.

Comment: imho, it would be fine to vote as you normall would, if you can do so without the meta discussion influencing your voting. In other words, vote as if you had never seen the meta post.

Comment: If you *read* the linked post. Like I feel that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924812/android-number-formatting-exception-when-taking-information-from-edit-text/11924974#11924974) answer might have been downvoted due to [a Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143339/accept-for-more-help-extortion-is-this-common). That Meta post claimed that yet another answer (now deleted) required the OP to change their database from integers to doubles. But I think the OP actually used such database all the time, but just erroneously used an integer in their code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> would it be fine to vote as I normally would?

Yes, it would.

Doesn't really matter how the question or answer got your attention, does it? You should vote on merit.